# How can I retry after exception timeouts , and remove from dict?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I want to increase the coverage of scraping the content and avoid getting timeout, but however I want if the page raise timeout error then retry again, but if the second round of timeouts increase the timeout counter retry the URL again with a max of 3 times, and if it doesn't increase remove from dict

```
async def _worker(self, i):
    while True:
        url = await self.fetching.get()
        if url is None:
            return

        #logger.info(f'Fetch worker {i} is fetching a URL: {url}')
        try:
            site = await self._fetch_rss(url)
            await self._processing(site)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError as err:
            while self.timeouts[url] < 1:
                logger.info("adding {}".format(url))
                site = await self.fetch(url)
                await self.process(site)
                self.timeouts[url] += 1
```

Comment: How does the code relate to what are trying to accomplish?  In particular, assuming it *doesn't* accomplish what you want, how does it come up short?

Comment: basically this worker. especially after `except asyncio.TimeoutError as err:` I want to retry 3 rounds , and each link will have a counter, but if the counter of xyz link it will remove all links that don't increase the counter

Answer (score 0):

In general the pattern I use for "try n times and error if I never have a success" is the following:

```
for _ in range(MAX_TRIES):
   try:
       # do something
       pass
   except Exception:
       # handle exception
       pass
   else:
       break
else: # A lesser-known syntax; else after for is only run if the for *wasn't* broken out of
    # We never broke, which means we never had a success, so handle the failure here
    pass
```